# How can I retain Vim undo history but disallow hiding modified buffers?

Tags: vim, buffer, undo

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732267/vim-loses-undo-history-when-changing-buffers), I want to keep my undo history when I change buffers. However, if I use `set hidden`, vim no longer prompts me when I switch from a buffer with changes.

How can I retain the unsaved buffer prompt but also retain my undo history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new persistent undo feature in Vim 7.3.

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
```

For details, see the documentation at

```
:help persistent-undo
```

Comment: Great! However, I had to add `if filewritable(&undodir) == 0 | call mkdir(&undodir, "p") | endif` after that to make sure that undodir exists.